# How to setup loopbackon my Windows Server 2008 Virtual PC VM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, sharepoint, loopback, virtual-machines

I am trying to setup a virtual sharepoint environment for development and need to be able to access my sharepoint sites on my host machine.  From hours of google research, I discern that I must setup loopback, but haven't been able to get it to work and can't find a detailed guide.  Can anyone please post a details on how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Do these articles help?

[Using Microsoft Loopback Adapter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708341(WS.10).aspx)

[The virtual machine networking settings in Virtual PC 2004](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833134)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a similar setup without problems and not setting up anything specific.
I've setup the virtual machine network to be bridged, and assigned it an IP on the network. Then from the host machine, I just connect to the sharepoint VM via name I've assigned it in the DNS. Or if you don't want to  use DNS, put it in your HOSTS file on the host computer. Just make sure that the name you use, is the same one as Sharepoint web is set up under.

The problem with the loopback comes mostly when you're accessing Sharepoint site from WITHIN the VM.

Comment: You would also use loop back in the case that the host needs to talk to guest, but the guest can't be on the main LAN for whatever reasons.